# The case of an initial velocity greater than final velocity with a drag force proportional to the velocity squared

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, velocity, drag

consider an object with a mass $m$ falling in a fluid with a drag force proportional to its velocity squared $(f=kv^2)$.
the governing differential equation can be found using Newton's second law of motion as
$$ A \frac{dv}{dt} + v^2 = v_{lim}^2 ~,~v(0)=v_0$$
where $A=\frac{m}{k}$ and $v_{lim}=\sqrt{\frac{mg}{k}}$ is the final velocity with the initial condition $v(0)=v_0$.
the solution of the equation is
$$v(t)=v_{lim} \tanh \left(\frac{v_{lim}t}{A}+ \tanh^{-1} \left(\frac{v_0}{v_{lim}} \right) \right)$$
where $\tanh^{-1}$ is the inverse hyperbolic tangent.

---

The given solution does reflect the physical phenomenon in the case of $(v_0<v_{lim})$ ie the velocity increases from $v_0$ to $v_{lim}$.

In the case of $(v_0>v_{lim})$, the expected physics "behavior" of the solution is that the velocity decreases over time (from $v_0$ to $v_{lim}$) and yet we never see such decrease when plotting the function due to the fact that the $\tanh^{-1}(x)$ function is only defined for $x<1~ie~(v_0<v_{lim})$.
So, is there maybe another formula that better describe the second case?

Comment: Your starting equation is incorrect.  The RHS should be zero.

Comment: Sorry for not understanding your remark, but what's an RHS? :)

Comment: Right-hand side. I don't think the comment by @ChetMiller is correct though; the RHS reflects the effect of gravity.

Comment: The $v_0$ is on the Right Hand Side of this equation $A \frac{dv}{dt} + v^2 = v_{lim}^2 ~,~v(0)=v_0$.

Comment: $kv_{\rm lim}^2 = mg$ with $v_{\rm lim}$ often called the terminal speed/velocity.

Comment: the right side of the equation is the square of the finale velocity, what's after the coma "," is the initial condition.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: @Farcher, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the software Maple 2022 to solve the differential equation, I end up with the solution

$$v(t) = v_\mathrm{lim} \frac{\frac{v_0}{v_\mathrm{lim}} \cosh(x) + \sinh(x)}{\frac{v_0}{v_\mathrm{lim}} \sinh(x) + \cosh(x)},$$

where $x = t \frac{v_\mathrm{lim}}{A}$.

This solution agrees with yours for $v_0 < v_\mathrm{lim}$ but is also valid when $v_0 \geq v_\mathrm{lim}$.

It seems to me that the solution given to you is simply only valid in the case $v_0 < v_\mathrm{lim}$.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer, it's weird how the two solutions are identical but one of them works while the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You were quite right to worry that the $\tanh(x)$ function seems not to give the solution to your problem but there was a function of time involved.

[image]

To keep things simple assume that $v_{\rm lim}=1$ and $A=1$.

$v(t)=1\cdot \tanh \left(\frac{1}{1}\cdot t+ \tanh^{-1} \left(\frac{v_0}{1} \right) \right)=\tanh \left(t+ \tanh^{-1} \left(v_0 \right) \right)$

Lets see what happens as the initial velocity, $v(0)$, changes relative to the terminal velocity.

If $v(0)=1$ then you get that $v(t) = \tanh \left(t+ \tanh^{-1} \left(1 \right) \right)=1$, as expected?

Now an example where the body will speed up with $v_0 = \frac 12$.

[image]

What you did not like about your solution was that it did not seem to give a sensible view of what happened when the initial velocity was greater than the terminal velocity.
So with $v_0=2$ your solution is as follows.

[image] $\LARGE !!!!!$

That final solution can be written in many alternative ways and here is a sample.

[image]

But this form of the solution might be the easiest to comprehend?

$v(t) = \dfrac{3e^{2t}+1}{3e^{2t}-1}$

and this form of the solution only seems to be generated by applications like WolframAlpha and Maple when the constants are given numerical values.

Comment: the problem with my solution wasn't the $tanh$ function, it was actually its inverse function (it's not defined for values greater than 1).

Comment: Well as I have shown when embedded in a $\tanh$ function that limitation seems not to apply.

Comment: I don't know how these software solutions work, but my formula isn't mathematically well defined, i only noticed that when trying a [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/) slider, the moment $v_0$'s slider surpasses the value of $v_{lim}$ the plot just disappears.

Answer (score 0):

It's not strictly true that the inverse hyperbolic tangent function is undefined for $|x| > 1$.  You can, it turns out,  extend the function to the entire complex plane;  and for real $x > 1$ (or $x < -1$), the function is complex-valued.

Under this definition, the $\tanh^{-1}$ function satisfies [the identity](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcTanh/16/01/01/02/01/)
$$
\tanh^{-1} (z) = \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{z} \right) \pm \frac{i \pi}{2}
$$
where the plus-or-minus depends on the value of $z$.  For real $z > 1$, the minus sign applies, and so
$$
v(t)=v_{lim} \tanh \left(\frac{v_{lim}t}{A}+ \tanh^{-1} \left(\frac{v_{lim}}{v_0} \right) - \frac{i \pi}{2} \right)
$$
Moreover, [we also have](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Coth/27/02/10/)
$$
\tanh( x - i \pi/2) = \coth(x)
$$
and so the actual value yielded by the function is still real.